# Input group text area not aligned with input-group-button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following input-group with bootstrap:

```
<div class="input-group" style="padding-left: 20px;">

    <input type="text" name="s" class="form-control input-sm">

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default input-sm" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
    </span>

</div>
```

The outcome is a text-area not aligned with the button:
[image]

I want the text-area to be aligned with the input group button

Comment: i tried your code in my project and its working fine, so i would say either you add a little more `CSS` in this question or there might be some other class be conflicting with your `span`

Comment: are they in a bootstrap column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, they are in a bootstrap column .

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        " your code should be there "
    </div> 
  </div>
```

[see here , your  code is given here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaVdQE?editors=100)

try it , it's working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure its formatted correctly in a bootstrap column, it's working fine on my end.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="input-group" style="padding-left: 20px;">
       <input type="text" name="s" class="form-control input-sm">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-default input-sm" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
       </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/rOdgOz)